# Setting up a python venv in vscode (macos)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I've poured through the current answers on this and none have helped. I can't get vscode to detect the virtual env I've created. I'm currently in a state where:

1. I added the path of the '/my/absolute/path/bin/python3' to the vscode default interpreter path.
2. As a result the linter is detecting the packages
3. However when I try to get vscode to execute the script it throws the "ImportError", therefore not recognizing the packages i installed in the virtual env.
   Addendum: if i run the script with `$python3 myscript.py` Everything works fine.

I guess I could just run everything in the command line but it seems like a shame. Anybody got leads on how to fix this?
Thanks already :)

Comment: did you select the venv as active interpreter? right lower corner should show Python 3.9.4 ('.venv':venv) or something similar. If not you can click on that and select the venv

Comment: hey thanks for responding :) Yes indeed I have that already showing in the lower right hand corner

Comment: OK then, was worth a try :). Does your terminal show (.venv) at the beginning of the line? If not close the (all) terminal and reopen it.

Comment: yeah it does. i mean i named it something different but i don't think that should matter right?

Comment: Hm, no that should be fine. Thats really strange. Sorry, that's all I got since I never used it on macOS myself.